# Are there any websites with lists of self-guided themed tours?

Tags: tours, history, self-guided

I'm planning a tour of the Anglo-Boer battlegrounds (e.g. Magersfontein) and significant sites (e.g. where Winston Churchill was captured) in South Africa. I'm getting all the locations and backstories from Wikipedia, websites, and books.

That got me thinking that it would be nice if there was a website where users can post self-guided themed tours, e.g. "Locations of the Second Boer War", or "The path of the Klondike Gold Rush", or "The footsteps of Jack The Ripper" (which actually exists at http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/london-tours/self-guided-walking-tour-of-jack-the-ripper-sites/), etc.

Although some specific themed self-guided tours exist (like the link above), it would be nice if there was a single crowdsourced site (possibly a wiki). http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/ is quite a nice format with locations and explanations of the significance of the locations, but being a private site it has limited tours (e.g. no SA tours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't crowdsourced sites, but there are some excellent professional ones. A few examples (I'm making this a community wiki so others can add their own):

- [Rick Steves Audio Tours](https://www.ricksteves.com/watch-read-listen/audio/audio-tours) (Europe) - free, available in [an app](https://www.ricksteves.com/watch-read-listen/audio/audio-europe) that supports downloading and maps. Most are generalist walks around city centers, but some are specialized, particularly the museum tours
- [Detour](https://www.detour.com/) - collection of well-produced audio tours for some US and world cities, most around $5/each, including a number on specialized topics (e.g. history of the Black Panthers, geology and earthquakes, spies, etc...)

Comment: Thanks @Zach. Those are both interesting sites. Detour is very professional, and Rick Steves seems entertaining. I'll definitely use both of them in the future.